# Wordpress and Wordpress-test-lib not getting added to tmp folder

Tags: php, permissions, unit-tests

I’ve installed the wpcli and php unit testing to my imac and the `wordpress` and `wordpress-test-lib` files were added to my tmp folder as they should have. I used this to install the setup.

```
bash bin/install-wp-tests.sh wordpress_test root <mypassword> localhost latest
```

I wanted to reinstall everything to make sure I had the process down so I could show others. However, after deleting the files from the `tmp` folder and reinstalling using the terminal command `bash bin/install-wp-tests.sh wordpress_test root <mypassword> localhost latest`
 `wordpress` and `wordpress-test-lib` folders are getting added to my `/var/folders/xq/zdm3rwn....` folder, but the `wp-latest.php` file is installing in the tmp directory correctly.

How can I correct this problem with the other folders not being placed in the `tmp` directory or is there another work around I'm missing? Or is this not a problem and I just need to adjust another file to point to the right directory now.

Here is the return info from terminal after running the install...

- install_wp
- '[' -d /var/folders/xq/zdmw3rwn5cn9_b9z05vs355c0000gn/T/wordpress/ ']'
- return
- install_test_suite
  ++ uname -s
- [[ Darwin == \D\a\r\w\i\n ]]
- local ioption=-i.bak
- '[' '!' -d /var/folders/xq/zdmw3rwn5cn9_b9z05vs355c0000gn/T/wordpress-tests-lib ']'
- '[' '!' -f wp-tests-config.php ']'
- download https://develop.svn.wordpress.org/tags/5.0.3/wp-tests-config-sample.php /var/folders/xq/zdmw3rwn5cn9_b9z05vs355c0000gn/T/wordpress-tests-lib/wp-tests-config.php
  ++ which curl
- '[' /usr/bin/curl ']'
- curl -s https://develop.svn.wordpress.org/tags/5.0.3/wp-tests-config-sample.php
  ++ echo /var/folders/xq/zdmw3rwn5cn9_b9z05vs355c0000gn/T/wordpress/
  ++ sed 's:/+$::'
- WP_CORE_DIR=/var/folders/xq/zdmw3rwn5cn9_b9z05vs355c0000gn/T/wordpress/
- sed -i.bak 's:dirname( **FILE** ) . '\''/src/'\'':'\''/var/folders/xq/zdmw3rwn5cn9_b9z05vs355c0000gn/T/wordpress//'\'':' /var/folders/xq/zdmw3rwn5cn9_b9z05vs355c0000gn/T/wordpress-tests-lib/wp-tests-config.php
- sed -i.bak s/youremptytestdbnamehere/wordpress_test/ /var/folders/xq/zdmw3rwn5cn9_b9z05vs355c0000gn/T/wordpress-tests-lib/wp-tests-config.php
- sed -i.bak s/yourusernamehere/root/ /var/folders/xq/zdmw3rwn5cn9_b9z05vs355c0000gn/T/wordpress-tests-lib/wp-tests-config.php
- sed -i.bak s/yourpasswordhere/mypassword/ /var/folders/xq/zdmw3rwn5cn9_b9z05vs355c0000gn/T/wordpress-tests-lib/wp-tests-config.php
- sed -i.bak 's|localhost|localhost|' /var/folders/xq/zdmw3rwn5cn9_b9z05vs355c0000gn/T/wordpress-tests-lib/wp-tests-config.php
- install_db
- '[' false = true ']'
- PARTS=(${DB_HOST//:/ })
- local PARTS
- local DB_HOSTNAME=localhost
- local DB_SOCK_OR_PORT=
- local EXTRA=
- '[' -z localhost ']'
  ++ echo
  ++ grep -e '^[0-9]{1,}$'
- '[' ']'
- '[' -z ']'
- '[' -z localhost ']'
- EXTRA=' --host=localhost --protocol=tcp'
- mysqladmin create wordpress_test --user=root --password=mypassword --host=localhost --protocol=tcp
  mysqladmin: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.

Comment: Can you be more specific about how you're doing this at the moment?

Answer (score 0):

enter code hereActually come to find out after further testing, these new set of folders, wordpress and wordpress-test-lib, that are now in the new directory `/var/folders/xq/zdm3rwn....` do indeed still work properly for the unit testing.

Hope that helps someone else wondering about this same issue. In all the docs for these installs that I have seen they all mention the /tmp/ directory which seems to work the first time you install, but if you delete those file (which after more research I found I should not have done) then on my imac the installs went to this new tmp folder as I mentioned.